# I need to create a function that filters a list without a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

so my function needs to filter a list so that it returns a list of only the values that return a positive value when a function is applied to it without the use of any loops. My code is currently:

```
def positive_places(f, xs):
    """takes a function f and list xs and returns
    a list of the values of xs which satisfy
    f>0"""
    y = list(map(f, xs))
    x = filter(lambda i: i > 0, y)
    return x
```

This currently returns a list of all the positive output values of the function, however I need their corresponding values from the original list xs.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What does "however I need their corresponding values from the original list xs." mean, can you explain?

Comment: Why can't you use for loops? A list comp is the cleanest solution here

Answer (score 5):

Using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
return [x for x in xs if f(x) > 0]
```

Without using a list comprehension:

```
return filter(lambda x: f(x) > 0, xs)
```

Since you said it should return a list:

```
return list(filter(lambda x: f(x) > 0, xs))
```

Comment: OP: "But list comprehensions have for loops!"

Comment: I would go through this route, but as I stated I can't use any loops

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions are possible using recursion, which do not use looping or comprehensions - which implement the iteration protocol internally.

**Method 1:**

```py
lst = list()


def foo(index):
    if index < 0 or index >= len(xs):
        return
    if f(xs[index]) > 0:
        lst.append(xs[index])
        # print xs[index] or do something else with the value
    foo(index + 1)


# call foo with index = 0
```

**Method 2:**

```py
lst = list()


def foo(xs):
    if len(xs) <= 0:
        return
    if f(xs[0]) > 0:
        lst.append(xs[0])
    foo(xs[1:])


# call foo with xs
```

Both these methods create a new list consisting of the desired values. The second method uses list slicing, which I am not sure whether internally implements iteration protocol or not.